# SAS proc freq table

Tags: sas

I need help in sas proc freq table.

I have two columns : TYPE and STATUS

TYPE has two values : TypeA and TypeB
STATUS has two values : ON and OFF

I need the sas proc freq table output as follows :

```
--------------------------------------------------
| TYPE |         STATUS      |
--------------------------------------------------
|      | ON | OFF | ON | OFF |

--------------------------------------------------
| TypeA| 33 | 44 | 22  | 55  |
--------------------------------------------------
| TypeB| 11 | 22 | 33  | 44  | 
--------------------------------------------------
```

How can I obtain this ?  I have tried:

```
proc freq data = XYZ; 
tables TYPE*STATUS/missing nocol norow nopercent nocum; 
run;
```

Comment: proc freq data = XYZ;
tables TYPE*STATUS/missing nocol norow nopercent nocum;
run;

Comment: Please paste that into the question, not here - too hard to read in comments.  Shall I assume your issue is that you don't know how to get the TOTAL column?  Are you tied to PROC FREQ, or can we use PROC TABULATE ?

Comment: I am sorry but I just changed the question table format. The above table displayed is what I am trying to get. Let me know if it is not clear

Answer (score 2):

PROC TABULATE is probably the easiest way to get that total column.  The keyword `all` gives you a total across a class.

```
proc tabulate data=xyz;
class type status;
tables type,(status all)*n;
run;
```

Comment: Can you check my edited table and suggest a solution accordingly?

Comment: Your desired table format doesn't make any sense.  Show example data and how it would fit in that format.